# Finding and removing the thousand separator in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have numbers formated like: 1.100.00 and would like to make 1100.00

These numbers are inside a huge line full of characters on each side, comma separated. This is the thing making the solution harded.

Couldn't find something similar to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Try [here](https://regex101.com/)?

Comment: Try a regex like `/\b([\d]+)\.(?=.*\.)\b/g` ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like so:

- Find what: `(\d+)\.(\d{3})(\.\d{1,2})?`
- Replace with: `\1\2\3`
- Search Mode: `Regular Expression`

Given this:

```
1.100.00
2.100.00
3.100.00
4.300.00
3.123.00
1.234.56
1.123
```

It gets transformed in this:

```
1100.00
2100.00
3100.00
4300.00
3123.00
1234.56
1123
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the regex below and replace with `$1`:

```
(\d+)\.(?!\d{2}\b)
```

See settings:

[image]

If you can have 1 digit in the decimal part, use a limiting quantifier `{1,2}`:

```
(\d+)\.(?!\d{1,2}\b)
```

In case it is overfiring, you can make restrict the pattern to check for the 2 digits after a comma before a space or end of string:

```
(\d+)\.(?!\d{1,2}(?:\s|$))
```